# Windows Phone 7 Popup problem

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm having this really frustrating problem that when I show a popup that has a ListBox with RadioButtons, the first item shows up cropped. I've spent almost two hours trying to fix it but I just can't. I know it's a really stupid problem, but I've ran out of ideas.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Basically the popup shows up when I press some button, and this is how it shows up:

[image]

And this is the XAML:

```
<Popup Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" x:Name="popupDateSelection" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="4" Width="400">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity=".9" />
            </Border.Background>
            <ListBox>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem.Content>
                        <RadioButton Content="Item 1" Checked="radioButtonDates_Checked" />
                    </ListBoxItem.Content>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem.Content>
                        <RadioButton Content="Item 2" Checked="radioButtonDates_Checked" />
                    </ListBoxItem.Content>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem.Content>
                        <RadioButton Content="Item 3" Checked="radioButtonDates_Checked" />
                    </ListBoxItem.Content>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem.Content>
                        <RadioButton Content="Item 4" Checked="radioButtonDates_Checked" />
                    </ListBoxItem.Content>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the whole XAML file. If I create a new project and put this popup in the default ContentPanel grid then it displays fine.

Answer (score 0):

`<Grid Margin="0,20">` maybe?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, the problem is with the ListView, even if I take out the margin it behaves like that. The only solution I could find is to put a Margin of "0,20,0,0" between the RadioButtons, but they are too separate from each other and it looks bad.

Comment: dont use it. take canvas or grid

Comment: Popus is lack of hardware acc.

Comment: So can you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: The Popup was talked down at PDC as is doesn't get accelerated (!?) true. They recommend just stick it all on the page (Canvas, Grid etc.) and then make it visible and translate it into place, or roll your own proper control.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Wolvorin -- Quite right, I think this was definitely one of my earlier answers on SO (apologies for the quality, or lack thereof). I'd normally flag it for removal, but the conversation with Luke and Lukas is useful enough that I'll leave it for now. Please let me know if I should reconsider.